# Prove that in a genus $g$ surface, a set of equal point masses not all diposed in $g+1$ geodesics has a unique barycenter

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact 2-dimensional smooth Riemannian manifold of genus $g$ and $S\subset M$ be a finite set. We define a barycenter of $S$ to be a point $p\in M$ such that

$$\inf_{y\in M} \sum_{x\in S} d(x,y)=\sum_{x\in S} d(x,p)$$

where $d$ is the Riemannian distance. Is it true that if $S$ is not contained in $g+1$ geodesics, then the barycenter is unique?

This conjecture is motivated by the following counterexamples:

- If $S$ is a set of equally spaced points on the equator of a sphere, then the south and north poles are barycenters.
- If $M$ is the torus obtained by identifying the sides of the square $[0,1)^2$ and $S=\left\{0,\frac 12\right\}\times\left\{0,\frac 1n,\dots, \frac{n-1}n\right\}$ then the barycenter is also not unique.

Comment: If we set $S$ to be the six points obtained by intersecting the sphere with the standard axes, it seems to me that any of the six points is a barycenter, but I might be missing something...

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon you're right that the symmetry of the figure guarantees that the barycenter isn't unique, but I don't think it's located at the vertices of the octahedron. Also putting the masses on the vertices of an icosahedron gets up to 3 geodesics.

Comment: You might be right. Still, would that disprove the conjecture, or am I misinterpreting the claim?